# Intelligent, talking zombies caused by dark water; one zombie kills another zombie

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

Looking for a movie with intelligent zombies that can talk, one zombie even kills another.

- Media: Movie
- What year I saw this: 2004-2009
- Tone: Horror/Comedy
- Setting: America
- Language: English
- In color
- Characters:

  - White woman, single(?) mother of at least one child
  - 2 zombies in a morgue
  - unlucky mortician
  - Very young girl (~10 yo)
  - Zombie with shotgun
  - Less intelligent zombie
- Actors: Don't remember
- Plot:

  - Opening scene: A woman turns on a sink, which shoots out water that's an alarming shade of black. Instead of being concerned, the woman just taps the side of the faucet until normal water comes out.
  - Dark humor: 2 zombies in a morgue decide to have fun with a mortician before killing her. She zips up the bodies, and one zombie unzips his own sheet. She zips him back up, only to find that the other zombie's sheet is now open. Dismissing it as a prank, she repeats this 3 or 4 times and turns around to confront the joker, only to bump straight into one of the zombies, who towers over her.
  - Ending: The mother finds out that the zombies have kidnapped her daughter for some reason. She follows the girl's screams and comes across a group of 4-5 zombies. One of the zombies tries to deliver exposition, but keeps getting interrupted every other sentence by another zombie, whose only line is "shut up, b****." Thoroughly irritated, another zombie whirls around and executes him(it?) with a shotgun. The woman then defeats the remaining zombies, rescues her daughter, and life returns to normal.
- What I've ruled out: Day of the Dead, Hide and Creep, Sci-Fi Original Movie.

Comment: By the by, very nicely detailed question.

Comment: This one feels like there ought to be a good answer, but nothing I've found so far quite matches the right points.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/201528/movie-with-talking-zombies-one-zombie-eats-his-own-arm

Comment: @jinkevin: it was your question asked around a year ago

Comment: @Shreedhar: LOL. The correct answer to that one was Hide and Creep, which I ruled out for this one above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though I think some details are a bit off, you're looking for Tobe Hooper's [Mortuary](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0415167/) from 2005 (starring *Star Trek: TNG*'s Denise Crosby).

> A family moves to a small town in California where they plan on starting a new life while running a long-abandoned funeral home. The locals fear the place, which is suspected to be on haunted ground.

The black ooze coming out of the sink (which infects and zombifies everyone), the little girl being kidnapped, the morgue shenanigans and the guy in the end who keeps interrupting a zombie holding a shotgun with "shut up, b****" and gets his head blown off for it, it's all there. Here's the trailer:

Comment: was not denise crosby in an stng episode that also involved black ooze? type casting?